# Free/Open source screen capturing library in java

Tags: java, open-source, frameworks, screen-capture

I am working on screen capturing tool. Currently my requirement is to capture screen shot of current screen, which can be extended to screen cast (video) etc. So just want to know which is best (open source/ free) java framework/library which meets my requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if you'll need a framework.

Check out the documentation for the java.awt.Robot class, specifically the createScreenCapture method.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html